# What does “themself” mean?

Tags: pronouns, personal-pronouns, singular-they, reflexives

My English teacher explained about *themself* and *themselves*.

I don't really quite understand though.

Comment: You have failed to present what it is you do not know, or what your teacher said, or how the dictionary confused you. Therefore, this question will be closed as the General Reference flavor of Off Topic unless you remedy that situation. ELU is not a 24-hour helpline for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) stumbling through English. Rather, ELU is “a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts.” Your question does not qualify for this site as currently worded.

Answer (score 3):

*Themself* is *himself* or *herself* when you don't know the gender or simply wish not to disclose it. There's even something more intricate here. There's ["*they*" that is singular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they) too!

Don't be fooled by the **them** part. It's still a singular. I find that confusing too.

In the future, provided that your English is at a beginner level, you might want to get more patient and rewarding answers if you turn to the other English-related site, [the one for learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Here, you might ask a question like: "*in what century did the word **themself** start to be spelled in the modern way and why did that happen*".

Comment: That would be the 14th century: *All þaa þat blisses þe Sal þam-self blessed be.*  Indeed, *themself* was the normal form even with the plural up through the mid 16th century: 1533 Sir Thomas More *Apol.* 7 b, ― *They se full well them selfe, that they saye not trew.*

Comment: And the OED's first citation of *"themself"* as the reflexive pronoun for the singular *"they"* is from the 15th century: (circa 1450) *Euery creature That ys gylty and knowyth thaym-self coulpable.*