# Can "themselves" be singular?

Tags: pronouns, singular-they

*(This is probably a duplicate, but I couldn't find what I was looking for through search.)*

Say for example you have the sentence:

> He is referring to himself.

You can replace "he" with "they" (singular), but you can't replace "himself" with "themself" because it isn't considered a real word.

So, would it be "themselves"? Can "themselves" be singular? If not, what would you use instead?

> They are referring to __________.

<sup>(Singular "they")</sup>

Comment: I think that's probably the most useful duplicate. If there's a better one, please add a comment nominating it.

Comment: It's addressed at [The hidden flaw in “singular they”—what to do about reflexive pronouns?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/216617/the-hidden-flaw-in-singular-they-what-to-do-about-reflexive-pronouns). But answers seem less than satisfactory (in general, not just those submitted there.) Then there's Rusty Tuba's recommendation in a [marked dupe](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/217699/themselves-or-themself-in-a-singular-context): 'Find a work-around'.

Comment: @AndrewLeach There is no very good answer to this question on the site and there are no well developed pages (i.e. ones with more than one or two answers).

Comment: Yes, there are currently 66 questions tagged [singular-they], including this one. [What does "themself" mean](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/182905/what-does-themself-mean) is also useful. But the one I nominated is the highest-voted, and is probably a good candidate for a canonical answer, if none exists already.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thank you for that link - it certainly does ask a similar question to mine, but as others have mentioned, the answer given is not entirely definitive. Should I open a bounty on it, or could you reopen this question?

Comment: I've added a bounty myself; and added a tag which will bump the question.